# I Can't adapt RecyclerView in RecyclerView at Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Using kotlin.

I want to make childRecyclerView in parentRecyclerView.
Maybe I think this problem is from recyclerView adapter.

Data is getting from Firebase. (Cloud Firestore)

I completed 'parent RecyclerView'.
And I also wrote adapting code for childRecyclerView at parentRecyclerView's adapter.
In parentRecyclerView, I asked to receive childRecyclerView's Firebase Data
And I checked through the log that this data was well received.
But my app show only parentRecyclerView's content.

This code is adapting code for ChildRecyclerView in ParentRecyclerView's adapter.
And I write this code at ParentRecyclerView's bind() function. This fun is also contain showing ParentRecyclerView's content(Like Glide for parentRecyclerView's ImageView).

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val queryText2: Query = db.collection("spiceTable")
        var queryText3: Query
        val storageRef2 = Firebase.storage.reference.child("scentnote/spiceimage")
        var j: Int = 1
        var detailSpiceList = mutableListOf<SpiceDetailValue>()
        queryText2.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
           //Loop in parentRecyclerView's content
         .addOnSuccessListener { documentx ->
          //Getting ChildRecyclerView's content from Firebase
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            nAdapter = context?.let { NoteSubRecyclerviewAdapter(it, detailSpiceList) }
            fragment2NoteParentItemBinding?.fragment2NoteChildList?.adapter = nAdapter
            val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 4)
            fragment2NoteParentItemBinding?.fragment2NoteChildList?.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        }
        detailSpiceList = mutableListOf<SpiceDetailValue>()
```

From ".addOnCompleteListener", To "~gridLayoutManager}" code is same with adapting ParentRecyclerView at my Fragment. (in code, fragment2Note)
I try to Log at end of addOnSuccessListener and start of addOnCompleteListener.

And addOnCompleteListener's Log is shown faster than addOnSuccessListener's Log.
I don't know why this code work like this.
And also i don't know why this adapter can't work.

At Logcat,

```
No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

this log is shown several time but i don't know their reason.

Please help...
And I'm Sorry because I'm not good at English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do like this

Declare adapter at the first stage with empty data.

```
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val queryText2: Query = db.collection("spiceTable")
    var queryText3: Query
    val storageRef2 = Firebase.storage.reference.child("scentnote/spiceimage")
    var j: Int = 1
    var detailSpiceList = mutableListOf<SpiceDetailValue>()
    nAdapter = context?.let { NoteSubRecyclerviewAdapter(it, detailSpiceList) }
    fragment2NoteParentItemBinding?.fragment2NoteChildList?.adapter = nAdapter
    val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 4)
    fragment2NoteParentItemBinding?.fragment2NoteChildList?.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    queryText2.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
       //Loop in parentRecyclerView's content
     .addOnSuccessListener { documentx ->
      //Getting ChildRecyclerView's content from Firebase
      // After getting data, you asssign data to adapter
      adapter.setItem(detailSpiceList); // You need to create function to attach data to adapter. (it is easy and common way)
    }.addOnCompleteListener {
        
    }
```